# Understanding why it doesn't copy correctly using memcpy

Tags: c++, image, opencv, memcpy

I have some misunderstanding about OpenCV 4.1.0 and memcpy in C++. The question is why the image is zoomed in a lot?
I read an image like this:

```
Mat img = imread("lena512.bmp", 1); // Black and White Image
namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("Display window", img);
```

[image: Input Image]

After this I have 2 byte array:

```
int inputSize = width * height * channels;
byte* pixels = new byte[width * height * channels];
byte* out = new byte[width * height * channels];
```

I copy the img to pixels array:

```
memcpy(pixels, img.data, inputSize * sizeof(byte));
```

And then I want to check if retrieving image is the same as input:

```
Mat image = Mat(width, height , CV_8U);
memcpy(image.data, out, inputSize * sizeof(byte));
```

[image: Retreived Image]

Comment: Most likely the width and/or height and/or channels is wrong.

Comment: Width of the image (pixels/8) and width of the buffer (bytes)  are probably different.  Many image formats require line widths to be be whole multiples of some factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Mat img = imread("lena512.bmp", 1); // Black and White Image
```

That's the problem, the comment is a lie, and by using a magic number instead of a named constant, you can't easily tell that's the case. `1` in this context means [`IMREAD_COLOR`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html) -- i.e. the image is always read as a 3 channel BGR image.

However, after the shenanigans with `memcpy` and raw pointers, you create new `Mat` in the following manner:

```
Mat image = Mat(width, height , CV_8U);
```

Note that `CV_8U` is equivalent to `CV_8UC1`. Hence, you create a single channel (grayscale) `Mat`, but give it 3-channel data.

Getting garbage as a result is the lesser issue. The much more serious issue is that you copy 3x as much data as the target pixel buffer can hold -- basically you clobber half a megabyte of memory that doesn't belong to the `Mat`. That can either end with a segfault, or some really hard to find bugs (in case you overwrite some memory used by other data structures).

---

*Update:* There's another issue that I've missed (thanks to @Micka for catching that). The order of parameters of the [`cv::Mat` constructor](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a2ec3402f7d165ca34c7fd6e8498a62ca) is rows, columns, datatype. It appears you switched width and height, although since your input image appears to be square (i.e. `width == height`) it didn't matter.

---

The correct way to allocate the second `Mat` would be

```
Mat image = Mat(height, width, CV_8UC3);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! 
Oh wow, what a silly mistake with that comment. Now with IMREAD_GRAYSCALE works much better. Yeah, about seg fault. I use it with OpenCL and sometimes my screen went black and restaring the whole desktop process and I was wondering why.
And if that was IMREAD_COLOR, why does it display grayscale?

Comment: in addition, in the Mat constructor, the order is (height, width, type) not the other way around.

Comment: @MIcka Good catch, completely missed that one. I think it didn't matter here since the input image was a square. I'll update the answer.